# gulp-assemble & gulp-watch not recompiling site when changes are made to data, includes or layouts

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, assemble

I'm having issues using `gulp-assemble` with `gulp-watch`. I want `gulp` to watch the entire assemble source directory (`data`, `includes`, `layouts` and `pages`) and recompile the site when ever a file changes.

I'm able to get this working correctly for `pages`, but `gulp` is not recompiling the site when changes are made to the `data`, `includes` or `layouts` files.

I've added a `watch` task to the [example gulpfile.js](https://github.com/assemble/gulp-assemble/blob/master/gulpfile.js) in the `gulp-assemble` repository:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');
var assemble = require('assemble');
var middleware = require('./examples/middleware');
var gulpAssemble = require('./');

// setup items on the assemble object
assemble.data({site: {title: 'Blog'}});
assemble.data(['test/fixtures/data/*.{json,yml}']);
assemble.layouts(['test/fixtures/layouts/*.hbs']);
assemble.partials(['test/fixtures/includes/*.hbs']);

// arbitrary middleware that runs when files loaded
assemble.onLoad(/index\.hbs/, middleware(assemble));

// render templates in `test/fixtures`
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src('test/fixtures/pages/*.hbs')
    .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble, { layout: 'default' }))
    .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_gh_pages/'));
});

// ============================================================
// my watch task
// ============================================================
gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function() {
  gulp.watch('test/fixtures/**/*.{hbs,yml,json}', ['default']);
});
```

If I run `gulp watch` and save a change to any of the `.hbs` files in the `pages` directory, I see `gulp` trigger the `default` in my terminal output, and I see the `.html` file in `_gh_pages` update with the change.

However, if I save a change to any of the `.hbs`, `.json`, or `.yml` files in the `data`, `includes` or `layouts` directories, I see `gulp` trigger the `default` in my terminal output, but I see no changes to the `_gh_pages` `.html` file(s). I have to run the `gulp default` task manually in order to get the changes applied to the `_gh_pages` files.

What do I need to change in order to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gulp-watch will only execute code inside the function for the default task, so to get things like data and layouts to reload, you'll need to move those pieces of code to inside the function (Just before gulp.src).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');
var assemble = require('assemble');
var middleware = require('./examples/middleware');
var gulpAssemble = require('./');

// arbitrary middleware that runs when files loaded
assemble.onLoad(/index\.hbs/, middleware(assemble));

// render templates in `test/fixtures`
gulp.task('default', function () {
  // setup items on the assemble object
  assemble.data({site: {title: 'Blog'}});
  assemble.data(['test/fixtures/data/*.{json,yml}']);
  assemble.layouts(['test/fixtures/layouts/*.hbs']);
  assemble.partials(['test/fixtures/includes/*.hbs']);

  gulp.src('test/fixtures/pages/*.hbs')
    .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble, { layout: 'default' }))
    .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_gh_pages/'));
});

// ============================================================
// my watch task
// ============================================================
gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function() {
  gulp.watch('test/fixtures/**/*.{hbs,yml,json}', ['default']);
});
```