# edit JavaScript files using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How can I find and edit an attribute value in a JavaScript file using nodeJS.

for example: If i have a file called app.js containing following code.

```
let title = "hello world";

document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = title;
```

how can I change the value of **title** `let title = "hello world";` or any other attribute using nodeJS.

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Read NodeJS file document, https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: try using fs module

Comment: Why do you want to programmatically change a JavaScript file?

Comment: It is just a text file, treat it as such.

Comment: currently I'm using a database to store some data. but I need to make the change itself in my Javascript file. this js file is written in ES6 and i will be compiling it into js using a gulp file and retrieve some data using the js file.

Comment: While it is certainly possible,better approaches exist. For example use a config file, and import it in app.js, then edit/generate the config. Or, since you're going to use gulp anyway, substitute some variables in the compilation step. Also the question reads like a classic example of a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to edit a JavaScript file using regex. my code is below:

```
  function updateFile(filename, replacements) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
                    var regex, replaceStr;
                    if (err) {
                        throw (err);
                    } else {
                        regex = new RegExp("(\\" + 'let' + "\\s* ]*" + replacements[0].rule + "\\s*=\\s*)([^\\n;}]+)([\\s*;}])");
                            replaceStr = "$1" + replacements[0].replacer + "$3";
                            data = data.replace(regex, replaceStr);

                    }
                    fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'utf-8', function(err) {

                        if (err) {
                            throw (err);
                        } else {
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        }
```

usage:

```
var file = src/app.js
var myNewValue = "Hello";

     updateFile(file, [{
                rule: 'newApp',
                replacer: myNewValue
            }], function (err) {
                sails.log.info((err));
            });
```

this will edit,

```
let newApp = lol; to let newApp = Hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse/edit JS files why not use something like JSON which is easy to serialize?

Your gulp task can write whatever values are needed to a file:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFileSync('./blah.json', JSON.stringify({ title: "whatever" }))
```

Then your code references the JSON file

```
const title = require('./blah.json').title
document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = title;
```

Comment: no the issue is my gulp file watches for changes on js files not only one file. there for I cannot use a seperate JSON file to store values, because from the above it only changes the json file values :/.

Comment: So modify the gulp watch? As @pawel mentioned, include detail explaining the actual process you are trying to achieve in the question. Editing javascript programatically is not likely to be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: @DilakshanSooriyanathan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171340/gulp-assemble-gulp-watch-not-recompiling-site-when-changes-are-made-to-data-i - this answer should explain how to get gulp to watch for changes to different files