# Create/Update JavaScript file/code using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I need to create a JavaScript file which should consist of code like this.

```
const students= require('students');
const lecturers = require('lecturers');

const people = [
    {
        name: 'student',
        tag: 'student',
        libName: 'students'
    },
    {
        name: 'lecturer',
        tag: 'lecturer',
        libName: 'lecturers '
    }
]

module.exports = people;
```

For the time being i managed to create this file using **fs** module in nodejs. Like this

```
let peoples = {
        name: 'student',
        tag: 'student',
        libName: 'students'
    };

let data = `
   const ${peoples.libName} = require('${peoples.libName}'); 
   const people = [
     ${providers}
   ]
   module.exports = people;
 `;

    fs.writeFile(".pep.config.js", data, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Fail')
      }
      console.log('Success')
    });
```

How can i  add values(people objects) to the array of people and add require statements to an existing file?. with the current method i can only add one data at a time. Like this.

```
const students= require('students');

const people = [
    {
        name: 'student',
        tag: 'student',
        libName: 'students'
    }
]

module.exports = people;
```

Comment: use code generators https://yeoman.io/

Comment: In a quick search I found several solutions that you can try like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46928689/8296184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way given your setup, IMHO: use anchors as comments to know the boundaries of your array:

```js
   const providers = [
//ANCHOR_PROVIDERS_START
     ${providers}
//ANCHOR_PROVIDERS_END
   ]
```

Then to update, something like:

```js
fileContent.replace(
  '//ANCHOR_PROVIDERS_END',
  `,${moreProviders}\n//ANCHOR_PROVIDERS_END`
);
```

You can also make a function to overwrite the existing content using the starting anchor.

However, maybe it's more flexible to use JSON:

```js
   const providers = JSON.parse(
     ${providersAsJsonArray}
   );//ANCHOR_PROVIDERS_END
```

So you can retrieve the array, alter it the way you like, and set it back into the file like so:

```js
fileContent.replace(
  /(const providers = JSON.parse\(\n)(.+)(\n\s*\);\/\/ANCHOR_PROVIDERS_END)/m,
  (match, starting, sjson, closing) => {
    const json = JSON.parse(sjson);
    // do something with json, which represents the existing array
    json.push({ some: 'new', value: 'is now inserted' });
    // inject the new content
    return `${starting}${JSON.stringify(json)}${closing}`;
  }
);
```

In this spirit, and because this becomes a bit tedious, you can also declare your data in a neighoring .json file, and read it from your `.pep.config.js` to populate your variable. You can even `require` it, but then be careful that `require`'s [cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) doesn't provide you with an outdated version of the JSON.